# INT 21H function#9 on win xp

Tags: assembly, tasm

I tried to compile and execute the following assembly code.

```
 .model small
 .stack 2000H
 .data
 msg db 'Enter $';
 .code
 .startup
 main:
 call readeq;
 jmp exitl;
 readeq proc near
 mov ah,9;
 mov dx,0;
 lea dx,msg;
 int 21H;
 ret;
 readeq endp
 exitl:
 end;
 .exit
```

The result was:

`Enter ê♦FGÇ= u⌠░ eê♦F_X├PS.Ç>‼m☺t♠eí  δ╕ ♥ΦyïHe☼╢]☺♥√;╟~      eâ= t♦Gδ≤∙GG[X├S3 
e9E☻tTïï╪X.Ç>‼m☺t♠eï↔â╟&;√}Φº r☻δ∩∙δ☺°[├QRS3█3 .Ç>‼m☺t♥â╟&e8♣tΦâ r♂δ⌠CYQ;┘t♣δ≡∙δ☺°[ZY├Φ╬ ╦Φÿ ╦Φ. ╦ΦH ╦Φ[ ╦╦`... etc.

How to fix this problem knowing that I use TASM and TLINK on Windows XP?

Comment: jmp exitl does **not** terminate your program.  It keeps going, executing garbage.

Comment: Int 21h /0 or Int 21h / ah=4c and al=return code

Comment: mov dx,0 is not necessary. you overwrite it with lea dx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To terminate your program properly, if it's a COM you can do a `RET`, or `INT 20h` (old CP/M way). If you are an EXE, use `AX=4C00` (0 is the exit code) then `INT 21h`.